# How can I prevent Mocha from trapping unhandled exceptions?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, addeventlistener

I am writing a test suite for a library that performs handling of exceptions that are not handled by a `catch` statement. The library listens to `error` events that trickle up to the global scope (e.g. `window.addEventListener("error", ...)`).

However, if I want to test whether it is *really* able to detect unhandled exceptions, I can't because Mocha treats such exceptions as test failures. And I cannot use assertions like `expect(foo).to.throw`, because if I use these, then the exception *is caught* by `expect` and is no longer an *unhandled exception*: it won't trigger the global listener that my library installs and that I want to test.

I've tried `allowUncaught` but that did not solve the problem. Here is an example test that reproduces the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/xhtml; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="node_modules/mocha/mocha.css" type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script>
      mocha.setup('bdd');
      mocha.allowUncaught();

      it("should be fine", function (done) {
        // Simulate an error thrown by asynchronous code.
        setTimeout(function () {
          throw new Error("error");
        }, 100);

        // My actual error handler is bigger than this. This is just to
        // simulate what my actual test suite does.
        function listener(ev) {
          // Uninstall ourselves.
          window.removeEventListener("error", listener);
          done(); // We detected the error: everything is fine.
        }
        window.addEventListener("error", listener);
      });

      mocha.run();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The test above should pass. However, when I run it Mocha reports one failure and one success! How can I get Mocha to ignore the uncaught exception and let my custom code handle it?

Comment: This is a great question.  It seems like there must be a documented way to temporarily prevent mocha from caching exceptions, otherwise, when using frameworks like jquery that rely on try/catch detection, it's very not convenient to get to the origin of the error.  Wrapping in a setTimeout is one way around it I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Mocha installs its own unhandled exception event listener on `window` and `allowUncaught` does not prevent it. What you need to do is uninstall this handler with:

```
Mocha.process.removeListener("uncaughtException");
```

Here is an example that temporarily turns off Mocha's unhandled exception handling:

```
  mocha.setup('bdd');
  mocha.allowUncaught();

  var savedHandler = undefined;
  before(function () {
    // Save Mocha's handler.
    savedHandler = window.onerror;
  });

  describe("without handler", function () {
    before(function () {
      // Stop Mocha from handling uncaughtExceptions.
      Mocha.process.removeListener("uncaughtException");
    });

    it("should be fine", function (done) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error("error");
      }, 100);

      function listener(ev) {
        window.removeEventListener("error", listener);
        done();
      }
      window.addEventListener("error", listener);
    });

    after(function () {
      // Restore the handler so that the next tests are treated as
      // mocha treats them.
      window.onerror = savedHandler;
    });
  });

  describe("with handler", function () {

    it("should fail", function (done) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        throw new Error("error");
      }, 100);
    });
  });

  mocha.run();
```

The first test will pass and will be counted only once. The 2nd test will fail, as we expect because Mocha's unhandled exception handler is in effect.

The reason you get one pass and one failure even though you have only one test is a pecularity of Mocha. It detects the unhandled exception and so it declares that the test has failed. But *then* your code calls `done` so Mocha declares the test has passed and counts it twice.

Note that the method used above is not documented and could break with future releases of Mocha. As far as I can tell, there is no "official" method to get the desired results.

Answer (score -4):

It seems to me that what you are really up against is a design problem. Global state is poison for unit testing. You'd have to get rid of the hard-coded dependency on `window` to make your code easily testable.

Perhaps you could make your component accept an object to attach itself to, on instantiation. Then you could test agaist any arbitrary DOM element.

Or, if you want to test against a window object, just pass in a different one. You could spawn a child window and use that. Mocha should be ok with that. (Take that with a pinch of salt, I have created child windows in some of my tests, but I haven't triggered unhandled exceptions in them.)

Comment: There are real life problems with what you suggest. When I have a fully developed test suite with 100s of tests, I don't want to make large changes to the way the suite is structured. I ran into the problem here while moving between 2 quite different implementations. The first was an ad-hoc implementation that allowed being manipulated in testing (it cooperated with testing code) so that the issue discussed here just did not happen. The 2nd is a more general library that does not offer the same flexibility. It took about 10 minutes reading the code of Mocha to fix the issue.

Comment: I don't see how your 2nd paragraph would work. There's nothing in my experience that allows "any arbitrary DOM elements" to be notified of unhandled exceptions. Oh, they do have the ability to listen to "error" events but these are not those generated by unhandled exceptions. Regarding the 3rd paragraph, it is not an unreasonable approach. I have used `iframe` elements when I build suites from the ground up. They do work but they do not work in all cases. For one thing, there are browser implementations for which listening for `error` events on the Window of an `iframe` just does not work.

Comment: 3rd paragraph still: and there are also various quirks to performing testing of code that must handle unhandled exceptions in an `iframe`. This brings me back to my first comment: simpler to turn off Mocha's exception handling, than have to revamp a suite for the quirks.